# TabBarController doesn't change selected index

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, ios11, swift4

I'm trying to change selected tabBarItem ( and Controller ) from index 1 to index 0.

This is my code:

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tabBarController?.delegate = self


    if UserDefaults.standard.double(forKey: "is_logged") !=  1 {
        // print always selectedIndex= Optional(0)
        print("selectedIndex= \(self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex)")
        self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0            
     }    

    }
```

Comment: is the call going inside if let?

Comment: Now it's ok! i've add in appdelegate: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions  self.window!.rootViewController as? UITabBarController != nil {
            let tababarController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
            tababarController.selectedIndex = 0
        }

Comment: then in my VC.viewWillAppear i've add:  DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if UserDefaults.standard.double(forKey: "is_logged") !=  1 {
        // print always selectedIndex= Optional(0)
        print("selectedIndex= \(self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex)")
        self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0            
     }    

        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** This will not work because your code is written in second (1 index) controller of tabbarController. UITabBarController only load first (0 index) controller on start.

Best way is to control this is in UITabBarController for that create subclass of UITabBarController and in it's viewWillAppear do some thing like this.

```
 /* viewWillAppear of TabBarController */
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        /* Check if user logged in */
        if UserDefaults.standard.double(forKey: "is_logged") !=  1 {

            // Select first index
            self.selectedIndex = 0
        } else {
            /* User not logged in */

            // Select second index
            self.selectedIndex = 1
        }
        //Current selected index
        print("selectedIndex = \(String(describing: self.selectedIndex))")
    }
```

if you want to do this in viewController then in viewWillAppear of  first controller do some thing like below

**below code updated**

```
 /* viewWillAppear of FirstViewController */
        override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            super.viewWillAppear(animated)

            // check tabBarController is not nil
            if self.tabBarController != nil {

                /* Check if user logged in */
                if UserDefaults.standard.double(forKey: "is_logged") !=  1 {

                    // Select first index
                    self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0

                } else {
                    /* User not logged in */

                    // Select second index
                    self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1
                }
                //Current selected index
                print("selectedIndex = \(String(describing: self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex))")
            } else {
                print("tabBarController is nil :( ")
            }
        }
```

Hope this will help :)

Comment: thank you!! I've tried but it always prints  "tabBarController is nil :( "

Comment: *FirstViewController = index1 Controller

Comment: @LuZa How you are initializing tabBarController. Share some code relevant to it.

Comment: on the storyboard I've set the class of the UITabBarController to my own custom class

Comment: yes, my initial controller is the tabbar controller and in FirstController ( index 0 ) i can change tabbar background color. In SecondController ( index 1 ) i am not able to change tab, and Controller, from 1 to 0 ( i am not able to change background color too )

Comment: @LuZa secondViewController only load when selected unlike Android where all tabs loaded at once (looked in to your profile :) ) if you are doing any thing in second controller then that will be executed only when you select that particular index by default only first index will be selected

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158100/discussion-between-abdul-rehman-warraich-and-luza).

Comment: Now it's works fine! :) I've set tabbarcontroller as rootViewController in appdelegate: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. thank you for your support!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why are you changing selectedIndex inside the viewcontroller viewdidload. As it will also show selected index view controller.

Please change it in viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear instead viewDidLoad.

Comment: you are right but the problem remains and selected index is alway 0

Comment: i'd like to change tab if the user is not logged in

Comment: you can use Tabbarcontroller delegate method shouldSelectViewController ...    - (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController 
shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController;

return YES/NO according to user login status.